# R Need to extract month and assign season

Tags: r, date

I am using R, and I need to set up a loop (I think) where I extract the month from the date and assign a season. I would like to assign winter to months `12, 1, 2;` spring to `3, 4, 5;` summer to `6, 7, 8;` and fall to `9, 10, 11.` I have a subset of the data below. I am awful with loops and couldn't figure it out. Also for the date, I wasn't sure how packages like lubridate would work

```
"","UT_TDS_ID_2011.Monitoring.Location.ID","UT_TDS_ID_2011.Activity.Start.Date","UT_TDS_ID_2011.Value","UT_TDS_ID_2011.Season"
"1",4930585,"7/28/2010 0:00",196,""
"2",4933115,"4/21/2011 0:00",402,""
"3",4933115,"7/23/2010 0:00",506,""
"4",4933115,"6/14/2011 0:00",204,""
"8",4933115,"12/3/2010 0:00",556,""
"9",4933157,"11/18/2010 0:00",318,""
"10",4933157,"11/6/2010 0:00",328,""
"11",4933157,"7/23/2010 0:00",290,""
"12",4933157,"6/14/2011 0:00",250,""
```

Comment: there is confusion with the word 'season". maybe modify the title to replace "season" by "quarter" to avoid confusion with astronomical seasons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the subject/title of the question, its actually possible to do this without extracting the month.  The first two solutions below do not extract the month.  There is also a third solution which does extract the month but only to increment it.

**1) as.yearqtr/as.yearmon** Convert the dates to year/month and add one month (1/12).  Then the calendar quarters correspond to the seasons so convert to year/quarter, `yq`, and label the quarters as shown:

```
library(zoo)
yq <- as.yearqtr(as.yearmon(DF$dates, "%m/%d/%Y") + 1/12)
DF$Season <- factor(format(yq, "%q"), levels = 1:4, 
                labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"))
```

giving:

```
       dates Season
1  7/28/2010 summer
2  4/21/2011 spring
3  7/23/2010 summer
4  6/14/2011 summer
5  12/3/2010 winter
6 11/18/2010   fall
7  11/6/2010   fall
8  7/23/2010 summer
9  6/14/2011 summer
```

**1a)** A variation of this is to use chron's `quarters` which produces a factor so that `levels=1:4` does not have to be specified.  To use chron replace the last line in (1) with:

```
library(chron)
DF$Season <- factor(quarters(as.chron(yq)), 
                labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"))
```

chron could also be used in conjunction with the remaining solutions.

**2) cut**.  This solution only uses the base of R.  First convert the dates to the first of the month using `cut` and add 32 to get a date in the next month, `d`. The quarters corresponding to `d` are the seasons so compute the quarters using `quarters` and construct the labels in the same fashion as the first answser:

```
d <- as.Date(cut(as.Date(DF$dates, "%m/%d/%Y"), "month")) + 32
DF$Season <- factor(quarters(d), levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), 
   labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"))
```

giving the same answer.

**3) POSIXlt** This solution also uses only the base of R:

```
p <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(DF$dates, "%m/%d/%Y"))
p$day <- 1
p$mo <- p$mo+1
DF$Season <- factor(quarters(p), levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), 
               labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"))
```

**Note 1:** We could optionally omit `levels=` in all these solutions if we knew that every season appears.

**Note 2:** We used this data frame:

```
DF <- data.frame(dates = c('7/28/2010', '4/21/2011', '7/23/2010', 
 '6/14/2011', '12/3/2010', '11/18/2010', '11/6/2010', '7/23/2010', 
 '6/14/2011'))
```

Comment: Thank you all, these are all very helpful responses

Answer (score 1):

Using only `base R`, you can convert the "datetime" column to "Date" class (`as.Date(..)`), extract the "month" (`format(..., '%m')`) and change the character value to numeric (`as.numeric(`).  Create an "indx" vector that have values from "1" to "12", set the names of the values according to the specific season (`setNames(..)`), and use this to get the corresponding "Season" for the "months" vector.

```
 months <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$datetime, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m'))
 indx <- setNames( rep(c('winter', 'spring', 'summer',
                   'fall'),each=3), c(12,1:11))

 df$Season <- unname(indx[as.character(months)])
 df
 #        datetime Season
 #1  7/28/2010 0:00 summer
 #2  4/21/2011 0:00 spring
 #3  7/23/2010 0:00 summer
 #4  6/14/2011 0:00 summer
 #5  12/3/2010 0:00 winter
 #6 11/18/2010 0:00   fall
 #7  11/6/2010 0:00   fall
 #8  7/23/2010 0:00 summer
 #9  6/14/2011 0:00 summer
```

Or as @Roland mentioned in the comments, you can use `strptime` to convert the "datetime" to "POSIXlt" and extract the month (`$mon`)

```
 months <- strptime(df$datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')$mon +1
```

and use the same method as above

#### data

```
  df <- data.frame(datetime = c('7/28/2010 0:00', '4/21/2011 0:00', 
 '7/23/2010 0:00', '6/14/2011 0:00', '12/3/2010 0:00', '11/18/2010 0:00',
  '11/6/2010 0:00', '7/23/2010 0:00', '6/14/2011 0:00'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: They have a datetime column and not a date column. You could just use `strptime` and extract the `mon` from the `POSIXlt`.

Comment: Sure, but look at the `"` in OP's mangled example data.